# Is it possible to access a string element without assigning the string to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a string index that returns 'o' from 'Python' but without assigning a variable name to the string.

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do? Preferably with some code examples

Comment: Do you mean doing something like `"abc"[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the elements of a string with an index:

```
>>> "Python"[4]


'o'
```